# The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed. styles.xml

Tags: android, xml, styles

The error I'm getting:

```
"The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed."
```

Using Eclipse, my styles.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<resources xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
   <style name="ToDoTheme"parent="@android:style/Theme.Black"> 
      <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item> 
   </style> 
</resources>
```

Comment: That means your XML has a syntax error.

Comment: post your styles.xml content

Comment: Pretty clear, your XML is not correctly formatted.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
    <style name="ToDoTheme"parent="@android:style/Theme.Black">
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    </style>
</resources>

Comment: Rollback explanation: Please do not correct your code in the question such that your question no longer makes sense because the source of the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

what's the `;` on the `<resources.../>;` item doing there. i'd get rid of it first.

Answer (score 0):

oh! it looks like you close `<resources .... />` too soon. you need to remove the `/` on the first `resources` to allow the closing `</resources>` to balance.

Comment: no, again...((<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<resources xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <style name="ToDoTheme"parent="@android:style/Theme.Black"> 
      <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item> 
   </style> 
</resources>

Comment: well...it certainly shouldn't be there.

Comment: well..as a last shot, i'd make sure there is white-space between items. `<style name="ToDoTheme"parent...` to `<style name="ToDoTheme" parent...`. if that doesn't work, i have no idea.